# How to configure Apache to connect parallel two Tomcat Versions via AJP

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, ajp

I was not able any suitable solution on the web and all my trials result in failure.

My goal is to set up Tomcat9(TC9) while Tomcat7 (TC7) is still running, so I can configure and test the applications without any interference for the users. After I finished the configuration I want to switch to TC9 so the URLs of the webapps do not change and the Users won't notice the change.

I set up successfully TC9 with an AJP Connector Port on 8010 and I used the existing config file of the httpd and copied the */etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-tomcat7.conf* to */etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-tomcat9.conf* and edited accordingly

`ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8010/`

However the old pass does not work anymore

`ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/`

There might be a problem with the URL as I implemented it like so:
https:////

I had several attempts with configuration of the ProxPass like

`ProxyPass /<webappgroup1> ajp://localhost:8009/<webappgroup1>`

`ProxyPass /<webappgroup2> ajp://localhost:8010/<webappgroup2>`

But how does the actual endpoint URL look like and do I need to deploy my webapps still as #.war?

however like this I always get the Browser Error This site could not be found.

I don't know in which logs i could find more Information what is going wrong.

An example for the ProxyPass config or input of any kind is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since the way Apache's configuration is split into files is distribution-specific, you should specify what OS are you using and add the contents of `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-tomcat9.conf` to the question. Tomcat's connector configuration and errors in the log files are also relevant: did you specify [`secretRequired="false"`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/ajp.html#Standard_Implementations) on the AJP connector?

Comment: BTW: I would use a subdomain for testing, so it will be easier to switch the two servers. Also `#.war` works fine, but `ROOT.war` is a more common name for the root web application.